# R: Check if value from dataframe is within range other dataframe

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to look up infromation from 1 dataframe in another dataframe, get a value from that other dataframe and pass it back to the first frame..

example data:

I've got a dataframe named "x"

```
x <- structure(list(from = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L
), to = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), number = c(30, 
30, 30, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39), name = c("region 1", "region 2", 
"region 3", "region 4", "region 5", "region 6", "region 7", "region 8", 
"region 9", "region 10")), .Names = c("from", "to", "number", 
"name"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

#   from to number      name
#1     1  2     30  region 1
#2     2  3     30  region 2
#3     3  4     30  region 3
#4     4  5     33  region 4
#5     5  6     34  region 5
#6     1  2     35  region 6
#7     2  3     36  region 7
#8     3  4     37  region 8
#9     4  5     38  region 9
#10    5  6     39 region 10
```

This dataframe holds information about certain regions (1-10)

I've got another dataframe "y"

```
y <- structure(list(location = c(1.5, 2.8, 10, 3.5, 2), id_number = 
c(30, 30, 38, 40, 36)), .Names = c("location", "id_number"), row.names 
= c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

#  location id_number
#1      1.5        30
#2      2.8        30
#3     10.0        38
#4      3.5        40
#5      2.0        36
```

This one containt information about locations.

What I need is a function (or command, or whatever I can throw at R ;-) ) that:
for every row in y: looks up if the y$location fits between x$from and x$to AND y$id_number == x$number. 
If a match is found (a location y can only fall in 1 row of x, or in 0. it is impossible for y to exist in two rows in y), return x$name to a new column in y, named "name

desired output:

```
#  location id_number     name
#1      1.5        30 region 1
#2      2.8        30 region 2
#3     10.0        38     <NA>
#4      3.5        40     <NA>
#5      2.0        36 region 7
```

I'm pretty new to R, so my first idea was to use for-loops to tackle this problem (as I'm used to do in VB). But then I thought: "noooooo", I have to verctorise it, like all the people are telling me good R-programmers do ;-)

So I came up with a function, and called it with adply (from the plyr-package).
Problem is: It does not work, throws me an error I don't understand, and now I'm stuck...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
require("dplyr")

getValue <- function(y, x) {
 tmp <- x %>%
   filter(from <= y$location, to > y$location, number == y$id_number)
 return(tmp$name)
}

y["name"] <- adply(y, 1, getValue, x=x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple base method that uses the OP's logic:

```
f <- function(vec, id) {
  if(length(.x <- which(vec >= x$from & vec <= x$to & id == x$number))) .x else NA
}
y$name <- x$name[mapply(f, y$location, y$id_number)]
y
#  location id_number     name
#1      1.5        30 region 1
#2      2.8        30 region 2
#3     10.0        38     <NA>
#4      3.5        40     <NA>
#5      2.0        36 region 7
```

Comment: This looks very very promising... Tomorrow I will have a go at implementing this solution on my "real" datasets. Small question: What dows the ".x" in the function mean?

Comment: That is the name of the dataset being matched to. I'm using the name you used.

Comment: After some alterations in my "real" datasets, I was able to use this solution. Since it is also the shortest code of the three solutions offered, I'm going with this one as tyhe answer.  I will also try to make the other two offered solutions work, and benchmark them.... crazybilly, Psidom and PierreLafortune: Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to match the columns of `id_number` and `number`, you can join `x` and `y` on the columns and then mutate the name to `NA` if the location doesn't fall between `from` and `to`, here is a `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)
y %>% left_join(x, by = c("id_number" = "number")) %>% 
      mutate(name = if_else(location >= from & location <= to, as.character(name), NA_character_)) %>% 
      select(-from, -to) %>% arrange(name) %>% 
      distinct(location, id_number, .keep_all = T)

#   location id_number     name
# 1      1.5        30 region 1
# 2      2.8        30 region 2
# 3      2.0        36 region 7
# 4     10.0        38     <NA>
# 5      3.5        40     <NA>
```

Comment: That works beautifully (and fast!) on my test-data... But not on my "real" data :(.. I realise I made a mistake in the x-dataframe in my example: the column "number" does not contgain unique numbers. So a left_join on this column is not an option (I think?). I will change the original post to the correct x.

Comment: x and y changed in original post.

Comment: Is the id_number in y always unique? if so, you can simply drop records with NA for each `id_number`?

Comment: No, id_number in y is not unique unfortunately.. Just realise that id_number is not a very good name for it ;-). I will change y in the example :)

Comment: y changed in example (and consequently the desired output changed too).

Comment: This is similar, you can still use the `distinct` function but use both `location` and `id_number` as your group variables. See the updated answer.

Comment: Unless your `location` within each `id_number` are not unique either.

Comment: Again: Works like a charm on the testdata, but not on my real datasets.. I cannot figure out why, brain-overflow :) I'll take a fresh look in the morning. Meanwhile: Thank you very much for all your help so far!

Comment: In "y", the combination 'id_number' with 'location' is unique.

Answer (score 4):

Another base method (mostly):

```
# we need this for the last line - if you don't use magrittr, just wrap the sapply around the lapply
library(magrittr)

# get a list of vectors where each item is whether an item's location in y is ok in each to/from in x
locationok  <- lapply(y$location, function(z) z >= x$from & z <= x$to)

# another list of logical vectors indicating whether y's location matches the number in x
idok  <- lapply(y$id_number, function(z) z== x$number)

# combine the two list and use the combined vectors as an index on x$name
lapply(1:nrow(y), function(i) {
      x$name[ locationok[[i]] & idok[[i]]  ]
}) %>% 
# replace zero length strings with NA values
sapply( function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 0, NA, x)
```

Comment: I like this answer better than the dplyr version, as it doesn't rely on merging the dataframes. Thanks!