# Two data frames, join ID's and position from one df if value is in the range of 2nd df

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, apply

Since yesterday I've been trying to solve my problem...
I think, the best explanation will be when I show you the example, so I have two df's x and y and they look like this:

```
ID_x <- c('x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8','x9','x10')
chr_x <- c('chr1','chr1','chr1','chr1','chr1','chr1','chr1','chr1','chrX','chrY')
start <- c(1,2,3,4,50,60,70,80,9,100)
stop <- c(10,20,30,40,500,600,700,800,95,1000)
x <- data.frame(ID_x,chr_x,start,stop)

> x
   ID_x chr_x start stop
1    x1  chr1     1   10
2    x2  chr1     2   20
3    x3  chr1     3   30
4    x4  chr1     4   40
5    x5  chr1    50  500
6    x6  chr1    60  600
7    x7  chr1    70  700
8    x8  chr1    80  800
9    x9  chrX     9   90
10  x10  chrY   100 1000
```

And the second one:

```
ID_y <- c('y1','y2','y3','y4','y5','y6','y7','y8','y9','y10')
chr_y <- c('chr1','chr1','chr1','chr1','chr2','chr2','chr3','chr3','chrX','chrY')
pos_y <- c(8,9,15,31,41,2,81,8,91,8)
y <- data.frame(ID_y,chr_y,pos_y)

> y
   ID_y chr_y pos_y
1    y1  chr1     8
2    y2  chr1     9
3    y3  chr1    15
4    y4  chr1    31
5    y5  chr2    41
6    y6  chr2     2
7    y7  chr3    81
8    y8  chr3     8
9    y9  chrX    91
10  y10  chrY     8
```

Now I'd like to map rows from 2nd df (y) to first df (x) based on range (start, stop) and chr.
I'd like to list all id's from y df (if they fulfill the criteria) to each row of df x.
Of there's no such id_y, then NA.
So the expectd result:

```
    ID_x chr_x start stop ID_y          pos_y
1    x1  chr1     1   10  y1,y2         8,9
2    x2  chr1     2   20  y1,y2,y3      8,9,15
3    x3  chr1     3   30  y1,y2,y3,y4   8,9,15,31
4    x4  chr1     4   40  y1,y2,y3,y4   8,9,15,31
5    x5  chr1    50  500  NA            NA
6    x6  chr1    60  600  NA            NA
7    x7  chr1    70  700  NA            NA
8    x8  chr1    80  800  NA            NA
9    x9  chrX     9   95  y9            91  
10  x10  chrY   100 1000  NA            NA
```

At first glance I thought that it's piece of cake, but when i tried to solve this... I tried several approaches...
Nested `apply()` with `ifelse()` was giving me a huge matrix with a lots of NA's...
I found similar problem and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536807/r-check-if-value-from-dataframe-is-within-range-other-dataframe/39537011#39537011) but my original data set is huge, df x has 134748 rows and df y has 865859 rows. I had the memory allocation error, even when I tried to do this with one chromosome.

Could you please give me a hint how to do this?

Thank you,
Adam

Comment: See `fuzzy_join` here an example https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a more efficient solution to this using `data.table` joins but here is one way to do it using `dplyr`. We first do a `left_join` of `x` and `y` by `"chr"` columns, then `filter` rows which is between `start` and `stop`, create a comma-separated string for each `chr_x`, `start` and `stop` and finally `right_join` with `x` to get missing range with `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(x, y, by = c("chr_x" = "chr_y")) %>%
   filter(data.table::between(pos_y, start, stop)) %>%
   group_by(chr_x, start, stop) %>%
   summarise(ID_y = toString(ID_y), pos_y = toString(pos_y)) %>%
   right_join(x)


#   chr_x start  stop ID_y           pos_y        ID_x 
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          <chr>        <fct>
# 1 chr1      1    10 y1, y2         8, 9         x1   
# 2 chr1      2    20 y1, y2, y3     8, 9, 15     x2   
# 3 chr1      3    30 y1, y2, y3     8, 9, 15     x3   
# 4 chr1      4    40 y1, y2, y3, y4 8, 9, 15, 31 x4   
# 5 chr1     50   500 NA             NA           x5   
# 6 chr1     60   600 NA             NA           x6   
# 7 chr1     70   700 NA             NA           x7   
# 8 chr1     80   800 NA             NA           x8   
# 9 chrX      9    95 y9             91           x9   
#10 chrY    100  1000 NA             NA           x10
```

Comment: Thank you very much, nice solution with `filter()` and `between()`. I'll try to run this with wohole dataset, thank you once again!

Comment: At the beginning It worked but suddenly I got the following error: `Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: Expecting a single value: [extent=34]..` Is that code works for you?

Comment: Yes, it works for me for the data shared. Although it gives me a warning of `joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector ` but that's because you have factors in your data.