# Two data frames comparison, how to add ID from one df to the 2nd one but based on condition and range

Tags: r, dataframe

I have to ask once again with similar question that I asked recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297579/two-data-frames-join-ids-and-position-from-one-df-if-value-is-in-the-range-of) but I still didn't get it, I have a new dataset and previous solution unfortunately didint work...

I have two datasets:

```
Input = ("     CHROM      POS    QUAL
1    chr10 10057508  223.60
2    chr10 10057509  223.60
3    chr10 10057514  223.60
300  chr17 18183700 1847.03
301  chr17 18377233  532.06
302  chr17 27975024   93.60
303  chr17 27975027  157.64
8000 chr12  6923083  217.60
8001 chr12 70920775  157.60
8002 chr12 70920776  157.60
8003 chr12 70920777  157.60")
df1 = as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection(Input), header = T, row.names = 1))

Input = ("         chr     start      stop                  merged
1       chr1      9868     11868          chr1_9868_11868
852     chr1   2814998   2816998     chr1_2814998_2816998
117618 chr10  10056721  10058721  chr10_10056721_10058721
185773 chr17  18181827  18183827  chr17_18181827_18183827
185853 chr17  18375777  18377777  chr17_18375777_18377777
186710 chr17  27974223  27976223  chr17_27974223_27976223
139286 chr12   6922462   6924462    chr12_6922462_6924462
145955 chr12  70920738  70922738  chr12_70920738_70922738
66558   chr5 132871443 132873443 chr5_132871443_132873443
78653   chr6 125818858 125820858 chr6_125818858_125820858")
df2 = as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection(Input), header = T, row.names = 1))
```

I'd like to put localisation ID's - column `merged`, df2 to corresponding rows in df1. `CHROM` and `chr` must be equal and `POS` must be in range `start`, stop of df2.
So desired output should be, I did it manualy, so mistakes are possible:

```
     CHROM      POS    QUAL merged
1    chr10 10057508  223.60 chr10_10056721_10058721
2    chr10 10057509  223.60 chr10_10056721_10058721
3    chr10 10057514  223.60 chr10_10056721_10058721
300  chr17 18183700 1847.03 chr17_18181827_18183827
301  chr17 18377233  532.06 chr17_18375777_18377777
302  chr17 27975024   93.60 chr17_27974223_27976223
303  chr17 27975027  157.64 chr17_27974223_27976223
8000 chr12  6923083  217.60 chr12_6922462_6924462
8001 chr12 70920775  157.60 chr12_70920738_70922738
8002 chr12 70920776  157.60 chr12_70920738_70922738
8003 chr12 70920777  157.60 chr12_70920738_70922738
```

Of course it's possible that two or more ID's present in df2 `merged` may fit in one row in df1. Then rows may be duplicated with different newly added ID's or listed with commas.

I made something like this but it doesn't work well, now I'm trying to fix it but I'm open to your help.

```
df1$merged <- sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x) sapply(1:nrow(df2),function(y) ifelse(df1[x,1] == df2[y,1] & (df1[x,2] > df2[y,2] & df1[x,2] < df2[y,3]), df2[y,4], NA)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work without duplicate IDs for ID1. BUT, what logic do you want done to the duplicated ID2?

```
library(tidyverse)

Input = ("ID1  CHROM      POS    QUAL
1    chr10 10057508  223.60
2    chr10 10057509  223.60
3    chr10 10057514  223.60
300  chr17 18183700 1847.03
301  chr17 18377233  532.06
302  chr17 27975024   93.60
303  chr17 27975027  157.64
8000 chr12  6923083  217.60
8001 chr12 70920775  157.60
8002 chr12 70920776  157.60
8003 chr12 70920777  157.60")
df1 = as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection(Input), header = T, row.names = NULL))

Input = ("ID2    chr     start      stop                  merged
1       chr1      9868     11868          chr1_9868_11868
852     chr1   2814998   2816998     chr1_2814998_2816998
117618 chr10  10056721  10058721  chr10_10056721_10058721
185773 chr17  18181827  18183827  chr17_18181827_18183827
185853 chr17  18375777  18377777  chr17_18375777_18377777
186710 chr17  27974223  27976223  chr17_27974223_27976223
139286 chr12   6922462   6924462    chr12_6922462_6924462
145955 chr12  70920738  70922738  chr12_70920738_70922738
66558   chr5 132871443 132873443 chr5_132871443_132873443
78653   chr6 125818858 125820858 chr6_125818858_125820858")
df2 = as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection(Input), header = T, row.names = NULL))


data<-left_join(df1,df2,by=c("CHROM"="chr")) %>%
  filter(POS >= start & POS <=stop)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very elegant and simple. Unfortunately I got some duplicates in df1, df2 has only unique rows.

Comment: When I used your example data, there was some ID2's that matched with multiple ID1s. Is that what you wanted? Because I am sure we can add more logic to fix that.

Comment: Actually that was the point to group rows (positions) from df1 by 2000 ranges from df2. For example now I clearly see that first three rows in the result are in one region. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `sqldf` to do a conditional join:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("SELECT df1.*, df2.merged FROM df1 LEFT JOIN df2 on df1.CHROM = df2.chr AND df1.POS BETWEEN df2.start AND df2.stop")


   CHROM      POS    QUAL                  merged
1  chr10 10057508  223.60 chr10_10056721_10058721
2  chr10 10057509  223.60 chr10_10056721_10058721
3  chr10 10057514  223.60 chr10_10056721_10058721
4  chr17 18183700 1847.03 chr17_18181827_18183827
5  chr17 18377233  532.06 chr17_18375777_18377777
6  chr17 27975024   93.60 chr17_27974223_27976223
7  chr17 27975027  157.64 chr17_27974223_27976223
8  chr12  6923083  217.60   chr12_6922462_6924462
9  chr12 70920775  157.60 chr12_70920738_70922738
10 chr12 70920776  157.60 chr12_70920738_70922738
11 chr12 70920777  157.60 chr12_70920738_70922738
```