# How do I subset observations from first data frame with start and end dates interval in which the second data frame's observation date falls in R?

Tags: r, date, subset, date-range

I have the two datasets (for example `df` and `df1`) and I would like to subset observations from the first dataset (`df`) that have date ranges in which observation date from second dataset (`df1`) falls within. Below is the example dataset.

```
#Create variables
    ID <- c(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),times =3),rep(c(6,7,8),times=4),rep(9,times =2),10)
    visit <- c(rep(1,times=5),rep(2,times=5),rep(3,times=5),rep(1, times=3),rep(2, times=3),
           rep(3,times=3),rep(4,times=3),1,2,1)
    StartDate <- as.Date(c("2020/01/01","2020/01/15","2020/01/29","2020/02/12","2020/02/26",
               "2020/03/11","2020/04/01","2020/04/15","2020/04/29","2020/05/13",
               "2020/05/27","2020/06/10","2020/06/24","2020/07/08","2020/07/22",
               "2020/08/05","2020/08/19","2020/09/02","2020/09/16","2020/09/30",
               "2020/10/14","2020/10/28","2020/11/11","2020/11/25","2020/12/09",
               "2020/12/23","2021/01/06","2021/01/20","2021/02/03","2021/02/17"))

    EndDate <- as.Date(c("2020/01/08","2020/01/22","2020/02/05","2020/02/19","2020/03/04",
             "2020/03/25","2020/04/08","2020/04/22","2020/05/06","2020/05/20",
             "2020/06/03","2020/06/17","2020/07/01","2020/07/15","2020/07/29",
             "2020/08/12","2020/08/26","2020/09/09","2020/09/23","2020/10/07",
             "2020/10/21","2020/11/04","2020/11/18","2020/12/02","2020/12/16",
             "2020/12/30","2021/01/13","2021/01/27","2021/02/10","2021/02/24"))

    #Create first data frame 
    df <- arrange(data.frame(ID,StartDate,EndDate,visit),ID)
    df


ID  StartDate    EndDate visit
1   1 2020-01-01 2020-01-08     1
2   1 2020-03-11 2020-03-25     2
3   1 2020-05-27 2020-06-03     3
4   2 2020-01-15 2020-01-22     1
5   2 2020-04-01 2020-04-08     2
6   2 2020-06-10 2020-06-17     3
7   3 2020-01-29 2020-02-05     1
8   3 2020-04-15 2020-04-22     2
9   3 2020-06-24 2020-07-01     3
10  4 2020-02-12 2020-02-19     1
11  4 2020-04-29 2020-05-06     2
12  4 2020-07-08 2020-07-15     3
13  5 2020-02-26 2020-03-04     1
14  5 2020-05-13 2020-05-20     2
15  5 2020-07-22 2020-07-29     3
16  6 2020-08-05 2020-08-12     1
17  6 2020-09-16 2020-09-23     2
18  6 2020-10-28 2020-11-04     3
19  6 2020-12-09 2020-12-16     4
20  7 2020-08-19 2020-08-26     1
21  7 2020-09-30 2020-10-07     2
22  7 2020-11-11 2020-11-18     3
23  7 2020-12-23 2020-12-30     4
24  8 2020-09-02 2020-09-09     1
25  8 2020-10-14 2020-10-21     2
26  8 2020-11-25 2020-12-02     3
27  8 2021-01-06 2021-01-13     4
28  9 2021-01-20 2021-01-27     1
29  9 2021-02-03 2021-02-10     2
30 10 2021-02-17 2021-02-24     1 




#Create second data frame
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
visit <- rep(1,times=10)
ObservationDate<- as.Date(c("2020-03-19","2020-01-20","2020-06-25","2020-07-12",
                            "2020-02-26","2020-12-16","2020-10-05","2020-01-01",
                            "2021-01-27","2021-02-18"))
df1 <- data.frame(ID,ObservationDate,visit)
df1

 
ID ObservationDate visit
1   1      2020-03-19     1
2   2      2020-01-20     1
3   3      2020-06-25     1
4   4      2020-07-12     1
5   5      2020-02-26     1
6   6      2020-12-16     1
7   7      2020-10-05     1
8   8      2020-01-01     1
9   9      2021-01-27     1
10 10      2021-02-18     1
```

I tried following methods suggested from a previous question posted here [How do I find if a date in the first DF falls within the range of dates in another data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401438/how-do-i-find-if-a-date-in-the-first-df-falls-within-the-range-of-dates-in-anoth). I did the following and I am getting errors.

```
#create dummy variable indicating 
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(ObservationDate, StartDate, EndDate), as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>% 
  mutate(dummy = ifelse(df1$ObservationDate >=  StartDate& date <= EndDate, 1, NA))
```

What I wanted to do was to create a dummy variable that will allocate 1 to an observations when the `ObservationDate` from `df1` falls within the `StartDate` and `EndDate` Interval from `df`. I was expecting an output as below.

```
ID  StartDate    EndDate visit dummy
1   1 2020-01-01 2020-01-08     1    NA
2   1 2020-03-11 2020-03-25     2     1
3   1 2020-05-27 2020-06-03     3    NA
4   2 2020-01-15 2020-01-22     1     1
5   2 2020-04-01 2020-04-08     2    NA
6   2 2020-06-10 2020-06-17     3    NA
7   3 2020-01-29 2020-02-05     1    NA
8   3 2020-04-15 2020-04-22     2    NA
9   3 2020-06-24 2020-07-01     3     1
10  4 2020-02-12 2020-02-19     1    NA
11  4 2020-04-29 2020-05-06     2    NA
12  4 2020-07-08 2020-07-15     3     1
13  5 2020-02-26 2020-03-04     1     1
14  5 2020-05-13 2020-05-20     2    NA
15  5 2020-07-22 2020-07-29     3    NA
16  6 2020-08-05 2020-08-12     1    NA
17  6 2020-09-16 2020-09-23     2    NA
18  6 2020-10-28 2020-11-04     3    NA
19  6 2020-12-09 2020-12-16     4     1
20  7 2020-08-19 2020-08-26     1    NA
21  7 2020-09-30 2020-10-07     2     1
22  7 2020-11-11 2020-11-18     3    NA
23  7 2020-12-23 2020-12-30     4    NA
24  8 2020-09-02 2020-09-09     1    NA
25  8 2020-10-14 2020-10-21     2    NA
26  8 2020-11-25 2020-12-02     3    NA
27  8 2021-01-06 2021-01-13     4    NA
28  9 2021-01-20 2021-01-27     1     1
29  9 2021-02-03 2021-02-10     2    NA
30 10 2021-02-17 2021-02-24     1     1
```

From this output, I wanted to use the code `subset(df,df$dummy==1)` to select required data. The overall required output would be as follows.

```
ID  StartDate    EndDate visit dummy
1  1 2020-03-11 2020-03-25     2     1
2  2 2020-01-15 2020-01-22     1     1
3  3 2020-06-24 2020-07-01     3     1
4  4 2020-07-08 2020-07-15     3     1
5  5 2020-02-26 2020-03-04     1     1
6  6 2020-12-09 2020-12-16     4     1
7  7 2020-09-30 2020-10-07     2     1
8  9 2021-01-20 2021-01-27     1     1
9 10 2021-02-17 2021-02-24     1     1
```

I would like to do this on a dataset that contains more than 20 000 observations. So I am looking for help on how I can achieve the results above, preferably using a shorter method.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the error you’re getting? Most likely issue is that your second `mutate()` includes `& date <= EndDate` but there’s no variable called `date`. Also, in your first mutate, you’re applying `as.Date()` but your variables are already dates.

Comment: Thank you for that. I have corrected the code to 
df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(ObservationDate, StartDate, EndDate))) %>% 
  mutate(dummy = ifelse(df1$ObservationDate >=  StartDate& df1$ObservationDate <= EndDate, 1, NA)) and I am still getting an error.

Comment: This is the error I am getting. Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(c(ObservationDate, StartDate,
  EndDate))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't subset columns with `ObservationDate`.
✖ `ObservationDate` must be numeric or character, not a <Date> object.`

Comment: `ObservationDate` is a column in df1 but not df, so you can't include it as a column in your `mutate` calls on df

Answer (score 0):

I have figured a way to do it. I am sharing my solution to help others who may face similar problem. I solved the problem in the following steps.

Step 1: Used the function `merge()` to merge `df` and `df1`.

```
df2 <- merge(df,df1,by="ID")
df2

  ID  StartDate    EndDate visit.x ObservationDate visit.y
1   1 2020-01-01 2020-01-08       1      2020-03-19       1
2   1 2020-03-11 2020-03-25       2      2020-03-19       1
3   1 2020-05-27 2020-06-03       3      2020-03-19       1
4   2 2020-01-15 2020-01-22       1      2020-01-20       1
5   2 2020-04-01 2020-04-08       2      2020-01-20       1
6   2 2020-06-10 2020-06-17       3      2020-01-20       1
7   3 2020-01-29 2020-02-05       1      2020-06-25       1
8   3 2020-04-15 2020-04-22       2      2020-06-25       1
9   3 2020-06-24 2020-07-01       3      2020-06-25       1
10  4 2020-02-12 2020-02-19       1      2020-07-12       1
11  4 2020-04-29 2020-05-06       2      2020-07-12       1
12  4 2020-07-08 2020-07-15       3      2020-07-12       1
```

Step 2: Created a dummy variable using the `ifelse()` function.

```
df2$dummy <- ifelse(df2$ObservationDate>=df2$StartDate & df2$ObservationDate<= df2$EndDate,1,0)
df2

  ID  StartDate    EndDate visit.x ObservationDate visit.y dummy
1   1 2020-01-01 2020-01-08       1      2020-03-19       1     0
2   1 2020-03-11 2020-03-25       2      2020-03-19       1     1
3   1 2020-05-27 2020-06-03       3      2020-03-19       1     0
4   2 2020-01-15 2020-01-22       1      2020-01-20       1     1
5   2 2020-04-01 2020-04-08       2      2020-01-20       1     0
6   2 2020-06-10 2020-06-17       3      2020-01-20       1     0
7   3 2020-01-29 2020-02-05       1      2020-06-25       1     0
8   3 2020-04-15 2020-04-22       2      2020-06-25       1     0
9   3 2020-06-24 2020-07-01       3      2020-06-25       1     1
10  4 2020-02-12 2020-02-19       1      2020-07-12       1     0
```

Step 3: Used the function `subset()` to select required data.

```
subset(df2,df2$dummy==1)

  ID  StartDate    EndDate visit.x ObservationDate visit.y dummy
2   1 2020-03-11 2020-03-25       2      2020-03-19       1     1
4   2 2020-01-15 2020-01-22       1      2020-01-20       1     1
9   3 2020-06-24 2020-07-01       3      2020-06-25       1     1
12  4 2020-07-08 2020-07-15       3      2020-07-12       1     1
13  5 2020-02-26 2020-03-04       1      2020-02-26       1     1
19  6 2020-12-09 2020-12-16       4      2020-12-16       1     1
21  7 2020-09-30 2020-10-07       2      2020-10-05       1     1
28  9 2021-01-20 2021-01-27       1      2021-01-27       1     1
30 10 2021-02-17 2021-02-24       1      2021-02-18       1     1
```